# From TFS + TeamBuild to Jenkins + Perforce

Tags: tfs, jenkins, msbuild, tfsbuild

Our current CI build process is all around TFS and its TeamBuild. We're evaluating Jenkins + Perforce as our future solution.

My question is how do I translate everything I have configured in the TFS build definitions to Jenkins in order to make it build my projects? My understanding is Jenkins uses MSBuild's config file to build. If that's true, does that mean I'll have to somehow have all the information currently in TFS build definition in MSBuild's config file?

Comment: That's an odd move. I take it you don't use Agile Project Planning or Test Management? What about Release Management? None of these things is offered by a Perforce + Jenkins model...

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins does not use any msbuild files per default. It might bpossible be possible using plugins though. Or simply calling msbuild which will have the same effect. If you know how to build from a commandline, its trivial doing it from Jenkins. Simply create a freestyle project and add a windows 32 shell command.